# How to get content of URL opened to determine whether Url provided is valid or not

Tags: c, windows

What is the best way to check if a URL is valid in c?

i am launching url using windows api (ShellExecute) and it always launches default web browser, whether url is right or wrong.

I'm not concerned about establishing a connection, just validity. Is there a method for this?

Comment: If you are looking to confirm that the URL's domain is legitimate, you could use `gethostbyname()`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [PathIsURL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773724%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from the Windows API.

Comment: Hi, PathIsURL only checks whether the given path is right or wrong,for ex http://www.ocean.com/ above api retrives TRUE but in reality there is no website by that name. So here i want validate the url by retrieving the error  message i got in the content of browser. I hope you got my concern

Comment: @dharani Sorry, I understood that you wanted to validate the format of the URL. In your case, you may use [getaddrinfo()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) function and check for the return value (for exemple, `EAI_ADDRFAMILY` if the adress doesn't exist). `gethostbyname()` is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the information i will try with the same.